# Automatic contacts aggregation does not work in android 4

Tags: android

I used this code to add a raw contact

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
  new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
.withValue(RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE,  RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DEFAULT)
.build());

....
getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

If I add the same information multiple times, in android 2.1 and 2.2 all
the raw contacts appear under one contact. But in 4.03 and 4.1, all of them
appear as independent contacts, although they are identical.

Is this a bug of the system or a feature? or it's just because I missed
something?

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

1) On Click off Button try the following:

```
       Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        in.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(in,ADD_DATA);
```

2) ONActivityResult Method:

```
     @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {

    case ADD_DATA:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

              Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor cur = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                ContentResolver contect_resolver = getContentResolver();

                if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String lookupkey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY));
                    String name = "";
                    String no = "";

                    Cursor phoneCur = contect_resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                    if (phoneCur.moveToFirst()) {
                        name = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        no = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        String lookup = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY));
                    System.out.println("Contact Name"+name);
                    System.out.println("Number"+no);





                    id = null;
                    name = null;
                    no = null;
                    phoneCur = null;

                contect_resolver = null;
                cur = null;
            }
       }
}

    if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {

        }

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }   
   }
```

Comment: Your answer starts an activity, I was trying to add contacts in batch mode. I have lots of contact to add in one time, so I can't start an activity. Also, Intent.ACTION_INSERT can't insert many fields (like Website etc) for android 2.X.

Comment: yes but in the same activity it will add the contact. It wont go to new activity as it is StartActivityForResult function... Here i am not going to any other activity to add contact... it will be in the same activity

Comment: I see. I edited my comment before I saw your reply. I used ACTION_INERT_OR_EDIT before and found that is very limited, I can only insert a few basic fields on lower version platforms.

Comment: you can insert all fields but before that you have to choose the adding contact selection like SIM or in PHONE, if it is SIM than it will tell you to add only NAME and NUMBER but in PHONE it will show all the fields